How to retrieve specific field from nested json field in mysql?
I have following column(descrition field) in my table of data in which I have to extract country name field value. Like Spain from this field.
[
  {
    "key": "country_code",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "key": "country_name",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Spain"
  },
  {
    "key": "timezone",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Europe/Madrid"
  },
  {
    "key": "latitude",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "40.37603"
  },
  {
    "key": "longitude",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "-3.69901"
  }
]


How to extract it? please help me out.
SELECT
  json_extract(description, '$.key[1]') AS country
FROM
  test_table;


Some ideas that may be useful to you, see dbfiddle.

did you mean something like that
SET @j = '[
  {
    "key": "country_code",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "12"
  },
  {
    "key": "country_name",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Spain"
  },
  {
    "key": "timezone",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Europe/Madrid"
  },
  {
    "key": "latitude",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "40.37603"
  },
  {
    "key": "longitude",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "-3.69901"
  }
]';

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_elem, '$.value') AS country_name_value
FROM JSON_TABLE(@j, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
  json_elem JSON PATH '$'
) ) AS jt
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json_elem, '$.key') = 'country_name';

Sample here : https://dbfiddle.uk/AgVBNJSd
